# Regular source for global carbon dioxide in the atmosphere

Tags: data-request, global, environment

I am looking for a regular (daily, monthly) Level 3 source of present day CO2 in the atmosphere. I have looked through [NASA AIRS](https://disc.gsfc.nasa.gov/datasets/AIRS3SP8_006/summary) and [NASA GEOS](https://gmao.gsfc.nasa.gov/GMAO_products/reanalysis_products.php) data products and could not find data for 2020. I did find contemporary data through [Copernicus,](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-carbon-dioxide) but it is too low resolution to use for a global map of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere, which is the goal.

I also researched the data sets at [JPL's CO2 Virtual Science Data Environment](https://co2.jpl.nasa.gov/) and those with global data were outdated, except for the OCO-2 data, but it was too sparse and low resolution on a global level to use for these purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is

https://data.giss.nasa.gov/modelforce/ghgases/

[image]

direct link to co2: https://data.giss.nasa.gov/modelforce/ghgases/CMIP5/CO2_OBS_1850-2005.lpl

another direct link to co2: https://data.giss.nasa.gov/modelforce/ghgases/Fig1A.ext.txt

Answer (score 0):

One option may be the monthly CO2 data from Mauna Loa

https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/ccgg/trends/data.html

data goes back to 1958 and seems to be actively updated:

https://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/ccgg/trends/monthly.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option has data going back to year 0 and up to 2014, sourced by ETH-Zürich:

https://www.co2.earth/historical-co2-datasets

> Datasets are compiled by the Institute for Atmospheric and Climate Science (IAC) at Eidgenössische Technische Hochschule in Zürich, Switzerland.

A full data page is here:

http://data.iac.ethz.ch/atmos/

including Terabyte (!) sized datasets